# How do I open a file I have the Uri for in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, file

I am trying to open an image I have stored on external memory. Here is the code I have:

```
File imagePath = new File(imageURI);
InputStream inputStream=null;
try {
    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imageURI));
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] originalImage = baos.toByteArray();
```

But it doesn't seem to be able to locate the file. The Uri is in the format content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A21.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In a project I am working on now I have external images in a directory on the SD card. I am using

```js
String thePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myAppFiles”;
        File imgFile = new File(thePath + " / " + "
externalImage.jpg ");
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 6;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File imagePath = new File(imageURI.getPath());
```

url.getPath() returns a String in the following format: "/mnt/sdcard/xxx.jpg",  without the scheme type pre-fixed